# How to get list of sets with Aerospike go client?

Tags: go, aerospike

With Aerospike aql tool it's possible to execute "SHOW SETS" query and get list of all available sets in a namespace. But how to get this list with Aerospike golang client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the "info" commands.

https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#RequestInfo

For your request, you will need to invoke the "sets" command.

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/#sets